# Active sessions window pops up randomly in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been using Google Colab for a few weeks now, with no complaints.

Yesterday it started popping the 'Active sessions' window up for no reason, no buttons pressed, every few minutes.
It does not tell me that I have too many active sessions, or requires me to do anything- It simply opens up, only to be closed by me.
It happens either if I'm at a different tab or while I'm in the middle of writing code in an active Colab tab.
You can only imagine how frustrating it is to write code like that...
I run Colab using Chrome on Windows.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this issue reproduce in an incognito window? Perhaps you have installed an unsupported extension that is taking actions in the UI, thereby causing the manage sessions dialog to appear.

Comment: Yes!  
It was Colab Alive, which hid among my chrome extensions.
Thank you!